# Python Sumy - no module named: sumy.parsers.html

Tags: python-3.5

I started using Sumy, a paragraph summariser for Python. I run their sample code but it gives me this error:

```
    from sumy.parsers.html import HtmlParser
ImportError: No module named sumy.parsers.html
```

I'm on the right version so it should work?

Sample code that I used from their website:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

from sumy.parsers.html import HtmlParser
from sumy.parsers.plaintext import PlaintextParser
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
from sumy.summarizers.lsa import LsaSummarizer as Summarizer
from sumy.nlp.stemmers import Stemmer
from sumy.utils import get_stop_words


LANGUAGE = "czech"
SENTENCES_COUNT = 10


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://www.zsstritezuct.estranky.cz/clanky/predmety/cteni/jak-naucit-dite-spravne-cist.html"
    parser = HtmlParser.from_url(url, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    # or for plain text files
    # parser = PlaintextParser.from_file("document.txt", Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
    stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)

    summarizer = Summarizer(stemmer)
    summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

    for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
        print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't work if your filename is named with '**sumy**'. Check that. Also check the python version for which **sumy** is installed and then run it.